# How to display SQL data in Wordpress?

Tags: sql, wordpress, orm

Does Wordpress has an ORM? How do you access data from an SQL server like MySQL and display it in Wordpress?

Comment: Check this as a reference. [Brian Swan](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2010/05/12/running-wordpress-on-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to interact with data in WordPress is using WordPress API, so you don't worry the compatible issue.

If you want to query the data by using SQL syntax, you can use [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).